# Module 'app': platform 'android-28' not found , android studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have upgraded my android studio to 3.6.3 and it download gradles but
When I start a project that is kotlin language , at the run time it errors:

```
ERROR: Module 'app': platform 'android-28' not found.
```

and my build.gradle :

```
   buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
      plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
    // belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
     }

    allprojects {
      repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

         }
     }

      task clean(type: Delete) {
          delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
```

and build.gradle(app) :

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28


    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kotlinapp5"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 
     "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

     buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
        optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.2.0'
}
```

I have tried to change googles services but nothing changed.

EDIT

and this is my sdk manager [sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJbiy.png)

and when I downgrade the sdk version it happens: 
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS99C.png)

and my gradle version : [gradles version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP3vr.png)

and lunch activity : [lunch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvXQo.png)

and my sdk tools : [sdk tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnWfx.png)

Comment: In the "SDK Platforms" tab of the SDK Manager, make sure that you have the API Level 28 SDK downloaded.

Comment: I changed it to 24 sdk version that i have it but it warns another error , please check my edit

Answer (score 3):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

finally I understand that my new android studio isn't connect to internet , because I am Iranian and google limited its services to us :(

I changed IP and installed SDK 28.0.3 and after that I did clean and rebuild the project .

just make sure your android studio is connect to internet when loading somethings like SDK Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your Project(root) level Build.gradle file has unstructored comment:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
  plugin:$kotlin_version"

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
 belong <----- ERROR: COMMENT IT
// in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }

allprojects {
  repositories {
google()
jcenter()

     }
 }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: edited , that is correct in build.gradle but here I mistaked ,sorry

Comment: You mentioned changing google-services, however i dont see any such dependency. Please add more context.

Comment: I added to my map project some dependencies , but this project is blank , both projects didnt work , please check my edit

Comment: Please upload what version of Gradle.wrapper you are using. Also go in the android studio preferences to see what version of Gradle plugin is installed. Also upload the sdk manager pic and not of SDK tools for more context. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is deserializing the Firebase response. Your User class has a different format than the one being returned.

Comment: check EDIT please :)

Comment: Please post the Launcher activity (with imports), thank you. Also try to rebuild as mentioned by @jd-lozano

Comment: sorry , what do you mean luncher activity?

Comment: First activity that gets launched is known as the Launcher Activity

Comment: is it possible that problem  belongs to dependency - implemenation in build.gradle(app)? becuase it notice me in affected module

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the sdk version try to clean the project and build it again.

Answer (score 0):

Install NDK then the error will be gone.
On Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager -> Select tab SDK Tools -> Install NDK (Side by side).

Comment: there is no NDK in sdk manager , please check my EDIT , I uploaded

Comment: Look at it carefully. There are 3 tabs, SDK Platforms, SDK Tools, SDK Update Sites. Select the tab SDK Tools then install NDK.